# Questions about conditions and trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

With $\gamma,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. I basically want to transform the quantities

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
i\frac{(\sqrt{\beta^2-\gamma^2}-\beta)}{\gamma} \\
\frac{(\sqrt{\gamma^2-\beta^2}+i\beta)}{\gamma}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

into trigonometric functions of $\sin{\theta}, \cos{\theta}$ etc.

I assumed $\beta,\gamma\geq0$ for ease of use since they are arbitary constants.

***First question:*** Is it correct if I set $\sin{\theta}=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$ with $\theta \in[{0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}$

and then transform $i\frac{(\sqrt{\beta^2-\gamma^2}-\beta)}{\gamma}$ into $i(\cot{\theta}-\csc{\theta})$?

***Second question:*** Is it correct if I set $\sin{\theta}=\frac{\beta}{\gamma}$  with $\theta \in[{0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}$

and then transform $\frac{(\sqrt{\gamma^2-\beta^2}+i\beta)}{\gamma}$ into $e^{i\theta}$?

I just want to know if there is any logical error with the conditions for $\theta$ or $\beta,\gamma$ and if they are wrong I would like a proper trigonometric representation if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$z=a+ib$$
$$=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}(\frac {a}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}+i\frac {b}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}})$$
$$=|z|(\cos (\theta)+i\sin (\theta))) $$